# Implement array in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I am planning to use Array to test Gmail login. You may have noticed that Gmail login 1st verifies username. I want to declare an array variable where I want to keep

> {"#John@gmail.com","John$u@gmail.com","john14@gmail.com"}

A few things I am getting confused about is how to send 1 name at a time and verify it.

Example:

```
    f.findElement(By.id("EMail")).sendKeys("$jon@gmail.com");
    //code below to get sendKeys value
    WebElement w= f.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    String emailID= w.getAttribute("value");
    System.out.println("Email id used " + emailID);
    if((emailID).contains(" # $")){
        System.out.println("Invalid character");
    }
```

***Confusion***: How to implement sending 1 name at a time and verify for invalid character and when it matches john14@gmail.com then print correct email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using ***[Data Provider](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/dataprovider-in-testng)*** if you are working along the lines of `testng` OR alternatively for `junit` give a try to [junit-dataprovider](https://dzone.com/articles/alternative-junit) .

Quoting from the example from the link :

```
@Test(dataProvider = "<nameYourData>")
public void yourMethod(<Data returned from dataProvider>) {
....// do whatever you want to test (in your case the method stated)
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData()
{
  //Rows - Number of times your test has to be repeated.
  //Columns - Number of parameters in test data.
  Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];
  // 1st row
  data[0][0] ="sampleuser1";
  // 2nd row
  data[1][0] ="testuser2";
  return data;
}
```